# jquery multiSelect not working with MVC using razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I try to use multiselect for showing dropdown select that allow multiple select using that library [jquery for mulitselect](http://file:///C:/Users/bilal.lilla/Downloads/jquery.multiSelect-1.2.3/demo/index.html) . i successfull achieve without using master page.
But when i use master page code give me error.("method not supported").
I am pasting the simple code that is not using master page and any one please give help me tht how i use that jquery library  using master page in MVC razor.

Here is the view.

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
@using LST.EMOTS.DynamicForms.Web.Models
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index1</title>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.multiSelect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.bgiframe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.multiSelect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#control_3").multiSelect();
    });
    function change1() {
        alert('this is called first');
        $('#hfHiddenfield').val($("#control_3").selectedValuesString());
        alert($('#hfHiddenfield').val());
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <select id="control_3" name="control_3[]" multiple="multiple" class="multiSelect" >
            <option value=""></option>
           @foreach ( Item itm in ViewBag.objectData )
           {
             
           <option value="@itm.Id" >@itm.Name</option>
           }
           
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="crtrlValues" id ="hfHiddenfield" />
        <input type="submit" value="GO" onclick="change1()" />

    }
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controllers.

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index1()
    {
        var model = new MyModel
        {
            SelectedItemIds = new[] { 2, 3 }
        };
        MyModel modelitesm = new MyModel();
        ViewBag.objectData = modelitesm.AvailableItems;
        return View();

    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index1(string crtrlValues)
    {
        var model = new MyModel
        {
            SelectedItemIds = new[] { 2, 3 }
        };
        MyModel modelitesm = new MyModel();
        ViewBag.objectData = modelitesm.AvailableItems;
        return View();

    }

}
```

here is the model.

```
 public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedItemIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> AvailableItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] 
        {
            new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1" , isSeleced=false },
            new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2" ,isSeleced=true},
            new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Item 3",isSeleced=false }
        };
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool isSeleced { get; set; }
}
```

This is the perfect solution but this works with out master page.
please provide me the soltuion that how i use it using master page.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is with not using `@Url.Content(..)` to get the path for rest of the js files. You are using it for jQuery js why not for other js files?

Try using `@Url.Content(..)` for all the js file hopefully it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Since you are using MVC try to avoid using relative path, always use `@Url.Content(..)` to get the path of the resource.

Comment: i did that too will any one plz provide me the solution of that why that did not work using master page. and suppose that @url.Content is used.....

Comment: When you use master page do you see the select element id getting changed? Is it still `control_3`? Can you check in view source?

Comment: problem occur for .multiSelect(); which is event of select list.

Comment: If even after using class selector it didnt work when using master page then I am sure the js files path are messed up. They are not getting downloaded on the page so are getiing `"method not supported"` error for `multiselect` plugin.